# Next js 13 SSR is not working in production

Tags: next.js13

When deploy next js app to AWS, Google, Vercel, SSR is not working, but i check on my local env, npm run build, npm run start, i check SSR is working. Can't understand why it is not working on prod.

"next": "13.4",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18",

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
const useFetch = async () => {
  const url = http://example.com;

  const res = await fetch(url, { cache: "no-cache" });
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};

export default useFetch;
```